# Hyperledger Indy: unable to init node, init_indy_node failed with error

Tags: debugging, hyperledger-indy

I am following the instruction at https://github.com/hyperledger/indy-node/blob/master/docs/source/start-nodes.md

My OS is Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS.

I have managed to install indy-node by following

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys CE7709D068DB5E88
sudo bash -c 'echo "deb https://repo.sovrin.org/deb xenial stable" >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indy-node
```

Now at step2, it says:

```
set Network name in config file
the location of the config depends on how a Node was installed. It's usually inside /etc/indy for Ubuntu.
the following needs to be added: NETWORK_NAME={network_name} where {network_name} matches the one in genesis transaction files above
```

I am confused as the document never mentioned any "genesis transaction files" above. So I decide to set `NETWORK_NAME = sandbox` in my case.

Now I start to generate keys with command `init_indy_node Alpha 0.0.0.0 9701 0.0.0.0 9702 --seed 111111111111111111111111111Alpha`, and I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/init_indy_keys", line 6, in <module>
    from plenum.common.keygen_utils import initNodeKeysForBothStacks
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plenum/__init__.py", line 87, in <module>
    setup_plugins()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plenum/__init__.py", line 50, in setup_plugins
    config = getConfigOnce()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plenum/common/config_util.py", line 106, in getConfigOnce
    return _getConfig(general_config_dir)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plenum/common/config_util.py", line 87, in _getConfig
    config.GENERAL_CONFIG_FILE))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plenum/common/config_util.py", line 32, in extend_with_external_config
    config = getInstalledConfig(*extender)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/plenum/common/config_util.py", line 26, in getInstalledConfig
    spec.loader.exec_module(config)
  File "/etc/indy/indy_config.py", line 2, in <module>
    NETWORK_NAME = sandbox
NameError: name 'sandbox' is not defined
```

Can anyone help to create node keys and init them.

I have referred to [Hyperledger Indy: Create genesis transaction file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59896480/hyperledger-indy-create-genesis-transaction-file) and looks like my problem is prior to this.

I have also tried von-network and I am able to start the network in docker image.

The only problem is I am not able to generate my own keys.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

OK.. Looks like I have found the reason: the indy_config file is actually a .py file, not a "pure" config file like json or yml, I need to add `'` for the NETWORK_NAME